# how to get the return value fancybox iframe onclose in codeiginter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, fancybox

i am using **Fancybox V1.3.4**. i have a problem with return the value of form submit to the parent page. i'm not getting the value from the current screen(child frame).

**ADD PAGE**

```
<div id ="app_fee_list">
     Fee Split/ Payment Details box 
<a id ="new_app_fee" href="<?php echo base_url('updateappraiserpayment/0')?>" ><i style="margin-left:15px;" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
                     <?php $this->load->view('andersion/appraiser/appraiserfeetemplate'); ?>
                </div>
```

Here fancybox code like this

```
<script>  
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#new_app_fee').live('click', function(){ 
            jQuery(this).fancybox({
            'width'             : '60%',
            'height'            : '90%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'onCleanup': function(){
                feeid = jQuery('#appfeeform').contents().find("#app_fee_id").val();
                alert(feeid);return false; // Here value returns Undefined.
               // If the app_fee_id filed is in Add page it will returns.But this field is not in the ADD page. It is in the SUCCESS page.
            },
            'onClosed': function() {
                location.reload();
            }

        });
    }).trigger('click');
    });
    </script>
```

it triggers to **updateappraiserpayment** page. After submit this form it will redirect to the **success** page.

**SUCCESS PAGE**

```
<form name = 'appfee1' id='appfeeform' action="<?php echo base_url('updateappraiserpayment/'.$user_id)?>" method='post'>
<div class="col-sm-12">

          <section class="panel">
            <div class="success">Appraiser fee information has been added successfully</div>
             <input type="hidden" name='appraiser_fee_id' id ="app_fee_id" value="3">   
             </form>
            <?php echo $appraiser_fee_id;exit; // Here i get the Inserted Id Value?>

          </section>
        </div>
```

Success message will also displayed in iframe.After closing the iframe i need to get the value of inserted value to the Parent Page. I tried like this also

```
$(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#app_fee_id").val();
```

but i am unable to get the result. Please give me any suggestions to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a value from an iframe page to the parent page, with js function running on parent page.

I think to get a value from iframe to parent, you need to write a js code in iframe page.

So, to a get value of hidden field 'app_fee_id' from success page to parent page, (assuming the value of 'app_fee_id' is filled when the page loads), write the following js function on **success page**,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    parent.$("#parent_app_fee_id").val($("#app_fee_id").val());
});
```

Add the following code in **parent page**,

```
<input type='hidden' id='parent_app_fee_id' value=''>
```

And update the following line of '**onCleanup**' function,

```
feeid = jQuery('#parent_app_fee_id').val();
```

Comment: hey we are all here to help each other :)

Answer (score 0):

parent.window.document

example:

```
parent.window.document.getElementById("parentPagetagId").value = 3;//set value for input parent page
parent.window.document.getElementById("fancybox-wrap").style.display = 'none';//hidden fancybox
```

I think it will be in a jQuery like this (but did not check):

```
$("#parentPagetagId",parent.window.document).val(3);
$("#fancybox-wrap",parent.window.document).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help websky. I've to assign a dynamic field value here. Main problem is i'm not getting the value from the current screen(child frame). Can you please help on this.